# What are the advantages and disadvantages of the Session Façade Core J2EE Pattern?

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, facade

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the Session Façade Core J2EE Pattern?

What are the assumptions behind it?

Are these assumptions valid in a particular environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Session Facade is a fantastic pattern - it is really a specific version of the Business Facade pattern.  The idea is to tie up business functionality into discrete bundles - such as TransferMoney(), Withdraw(), Deposit()...  So that your UI code is accessing things in terms of business operations instead of low level data access or other details that it shouldn't have to be concerned with.

Specifically with the Session Facade - you use a Session EJB to act as the business facade - which is nice cause then you can take advantage of all the J2EE services (authentication/authorization, transactions, etc)...

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage of the Session Facade pattern is that you can divide up a J2EE application into logical groups by business functionality. A Session Facade will be called by a POJO from the UI (i.e. a Business Delegate), and have references to appropriate Data Access Objects. E.g. a PersonSessionFacade would be called by the PersonBusinessDelegate and then it could call the PersonDAO. The methods on the PersonSessionFacade will, at the very least, follow the CRUD pattern (Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete).

Typically, most Session Facades are implemented as stateless session EJBs. Or if you're in Spring land using AOP for transactions, you can create a service POJO that which can be all the join points for your transaction manager.

Another advantage of the SessionFacade pattern is that any J2EE developer with a modicum of experience will immediately understand you.

Disadvantages of the SessionFacade pattern: it assumes a specific enterprise architecture that is constrained by the limits of the J2EE 1.4 specification (see Rod Johnson's books for these criticisms). The most damaging disadvantage is that it is more complicated than necessary. In most enterprise *web* applications, you'll need a servlet container, and most of the stress in a web application will be at the tier that handles HttpRequests or database access. Consequently, it doesn't seem worthwhile to deploy the servlet container in a separate process space from the EJB container. I.e. remote calls to EJBs create more pain than gain.

Answer (score 0):

Rod Johnson claims that the main reason you'd want to use a Session Facade is if you're doing container managed transactions - which aren't necessary with more modern frameworks (like Spring.)

He says that if you have business logic - put it in the POJO. (Which I agree with - I think its a more object-oriented approach - rather than implementing a session EJB.)
http://forum.springframework.org/showthread.php?t=18155

Happy to hear contrasting arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that whenever you talk about anything J2EE related - there are always a whole bunch of assumptions behind the scenes - which people assume one way or the other - which then leads to confusion. (I probably could have made the question clearer too.)

Assuming (a) we want to use container managed transactions in a strict sense through the EJB specification then

Session facades are a good idea - because they abstract away the low-level database transactions to be able to provide higher level application transaction management.

Assuming (b) that you mean the general architectural concept of the session façade - then

Decoupling services and consumers and providing a friendly interface over the top of this is a good idea. Computer science has solved lots of problems by 'adding an additional layer of indirection'.

Rod Johnson writes "SLSBs with remote interfaces provide a very good solution for distributed applications built over RMI. However, this is a minority requirement. Experience has shown that we don't want to use distributed architecture unless forced to by requirements. We can still service remote clients if necessary by implementing a remoting façade on top of a good co-located object model." (Johnson, R "J2EE Development without EJB" p119.)

Assuming (c) that you consider the EJB specification (and in particular the session façade component) to be a blight on the landscape of good design then:

Rod Johnson writes
"In general, there are not many reasons you would use a local SLSB at all in a Spring application, as Spring provides more capable declarative transaction management than EJB, and CMT is normally the main motivation for using local SLSBs. So you might not need th EJB layer at all. " http://forum.springframework.org/showthread.php?t=18155

In an environment where performance and scalability of the web server are the primary concerns - and cost is an issue - then the session facade architecture looks less attractive - it can be simpler to talk directly to the datbase (although this is more about tiering.)